# Data Insertion error while trying to insert a json array?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I am trying to send a json array to mysql data base using google's volley library.
The following is the type of data I am sending:-

```
[{"vatno":"","area":"Testing bay","status":"0","cstno":"","dbname":"webappdb","name":"ANUP BORDE","emp_role":"Manager","password":"1223","key":"","city":"Pune","shop_name":"Test Shop","mobile":"8600931386"}]
```

I get a data insertion error something like :-

> Data insertion errorYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'key,dbname,status,role)VALUES( '', 'ANUP BORDE',
>   '8600931386', '1223', 'Test Sho' at line 1

I am trying to run this php script.

```
<?php

        include "config.php";
        $dbname ="goldmine";
        $con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$dbname);
         if(!$con)
         {
           echo "Connection Error".mysqli_connect_error();
         }
         else{
        //echo "";
         }

        $arrAssoc = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['jsonarray']), true);
        $values="";
        foreach($arrAssoc as $aa){
                $values.="(";
                $values.=" '".$aa['']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['name']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['mobile']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['password']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['shop_name']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['area']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['city']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['vatno']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['cstno']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['key']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['dbname']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['status']."',";
                $values.=" '".$aa['role']."'";
                $values.="),";
        }
        $values=rtrim($values,',');
                //Insert into goldmine_users (name,mobile,password,role)Values('Anup','8600931386','123','admin');

        $query="INSERT INTO goldmine_users(name,mobile,password,shop_name,area,city,vatno,cstno,key,dbname,status,role)VALUES".$values;

        if(mysqli_query($con,$query))
        {
        echo "Data inserted";
        }else
        {
       echo "Data insertion error".mysqli_error($con);
        }


?>
```

And this is my volley code to send the data to mysql database.

```
public void registerUser()
{
    final String jsonArray = rolejson.toString().trim();
    Log.d("JSON RESPONSE",jsonArray);
    StringRequest stringReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTERUSER, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            Log.d("USER INFO RESPONSE",response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Log.d("LOG_USERINFO", jsonArray);
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(KEY_JSONARRAY, jsonArray);
            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    rq.add(stringReq);
}
```

This is how my database looks like:-
[image]

Any help or suggestion is welcome.I think I am doing a silly mistake somewhere it would be great if someone would guide me to the correct solution.

Comment: "key" is a reserved keyword for most database implementations. Did you make sure to escape it in back ticks or something similar?

Comment: Thank you so much @911DidBush.you solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $query="INSERT INTO goldmine_users(name,mobile,password,shop_name,area,city,vatno,cstno,key,dbname,status,role)VALUES".$values;
```

key is a reserved keyword and should therefor be escaped in backticks (or something similar)

```
 $query="INSERT INTO goldmine_users(`name`,`mobile`,`password`,`shop_name`,`area`,`city`,`vatno`,`cstno`,`key`,`dbname`,`status`,`role`)VALUES".$values;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your amount of columns and the data you want to insert doesn't match. You're trying to insert data in 12 columns however you deliver 13 columns of data:

```
            $values.="(";
            $values.=" '".$aa['']."',"; //Remove this line
            $values.=" '".$aa['name']."',";
            $values.=" '".$aa['mobile']."',";
            $values.=" '".$aa['password']."',";
            $values.=" '".$aa['shop_name']."',";
            $values.=" '".$aa['area']."',";
            $values.=" '".$aa['city']."',";
            $values.=" '".$aa['vatno']."',";
            $values.=" '".$aa['cstno']."',";
            $values.=" '".$aa['key']."',";
            $values.=" '".$aa['dbname']."',";
            $values.=" '".$aa['status']."',";
            $values.=" '".$aa['role']."'";
            $values.="),";

//12 columns

$query="INSERT INTO goldmine_users(name,mobile,password,shop_name,area,city,vatno,cstno,key,dbname,status,role)VALUES".$values;
```

Comment: I did remove that line it doesn't work it gives me the same error.

Comment: Can you do an `echo $values;` after the foreach, and post the result in your question?

Comment: @user3295583 deleted my answer as Daan has suggested same thing.

Comment: Rohit I cant delete your answer.You will have to delete your answer.Thank you anyways.